# Windows 10 (UWP) manifest issue

Tags: uwp

My UWP app has these package.manifest extensions content:

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>MobilePos.Win10.exe</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PclUtilitiesUniversel.CompanionInfo" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PclUtilitiesUniversel.DeviceManager" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>PCLServiceUniversel.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.TransOut" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.PCLService" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.TransIn" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

But when i compile (tried to rebuild in debug/release mode too) the project, appxmanifest.xml generated has a new "CLRHost.dll" tag added automatically, that generate error (in Visual Studio 2015):

> error C00CE012: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must
>   be valid as per schema: Line 63, Column 8, Reason: In base a quanto
>   definito nella DTD o nello schema, il contenuto dell'elemento
>   "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}InProcessServer"
>   è incompleto. Previsto:
>   {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}ActivatableClass.

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>MobilePos.exe</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PclUtilitiesUniversel.CompanionInfo" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PclUtilitiesUniversel.DeviceManager" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>PCLServiceUniversel.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.TransOut" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.PCLService" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.TransIn" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>CLRHost.dll</Path>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Why during building tags "**CLRHost.dll**" is added?
Where i'm wrong in manifest data?

Thank you for any suggestions,
Lewix

**UPDATE**
Seems adding only these tags (only one dll) project build successfully

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>PCLServiceUniversel.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.TransOut" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.PCLService" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="PCLServiceUniversel.TransIn" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why during building tags "CLRHost.dll" is added? Where i'm wrong in manifest data?

You can refer to the official document: [Side-loaded applications in detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps#side-loaded-applications-in-detail). It is said: there is one additional detail: declaring the availablity of the RuntimeClass in the side-loaded application's manifest.

And you can follow the instruction [VS2015TemplateBrokeredComponents](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/10be07b3-67ef-4e02-9243-01b78cd27935) to configure your manifest file.

No.9 step: Update the AppxManifest to specify where the definition of the Brokered component is using this XML:

```xml
  <Extensions>    
    <  Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">    
      <InProcessServer>   
        <Path>clrhost.dll</Path>    
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="[Fully Qualified Name of Brokered Component]" ThreadingModel="MTA">    
          <ActivatableClassAttribute Name="DesktopApplicationPath" Type="string" Value="[Path to location of Brokered Components and ProxyStub]" />    
        </ActivatableClass>    
      </InProcessServer  >    
    </Extension>    
  </Extensions>
```

Comment: Thank you grace, if you see my updated post, seems i have to declare only the dll reference

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni, did you test declare `MobilePos.exe` only? And did you tried to declare the clrhost.dll as in document with both inProcessServer?

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni, Just noticed that your Path `MobilePos.exe`, it doesn't look like a broker component, what is your `MobilePos.exe`?

Comment: MobilePos.exe is the main executable of the UWP app. I inserted this exe because i received from my customer the library and a demo uwp app; i didn't have details how to include the library (PCLServiceUniversel.dll) into my project, so i inspetcted appx manifest generated inside the package of the demo app (unzipping it) and i saw main executable of the demo app was included this way  ----- 
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>MobilePos.exe</Path>................ 
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>

Comment: I know, I have to learn how broker components work and how to use them in a uwp project

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni, you mean using another UWP app in your uwp app?

Comment: No, MobilePos.exe is exactly the main exe of my app, no other apps are linked/referenced. I have only copied manifest schema of the other test app received from my customer; its schema infact included his own exe inside manifest as inprocess server.

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni,  Generally we won't use .exe in IPC, we only using .dll in the IPC, if the lib is a traditional class lib, we usually compile this as a winmdobj, and use brokered component and IPC to use this lib in your uwp app. It's not right to include your main exe in IPC. But if your lib is for universal app, it is very easy, you can just add reference in your uwp app and reference to this lib.

Comment: Yes my library is for UWP, its files are mPosLiteUWP.dll (referenced to my project), PCLServiceUniversel.winmd (referenced to my project) and PclUtilitiesUniversel.winmd (referenced to my project). This library use bluetooth comunication in background and needs inprocess server. With these referenced files in my project app works without issues (i can call and use its methods). Do you think i missed something in manifest declaration (as i said i only declared PCLServiceUniversel.dll as inprocess server)

Comment: @LuiginoDeTogni, yes, it's possible, maybe you need to declare all .dll as inprocess server, and is that possible that you ask your customer (where you get your lib and app from) for how to declare your manifest?

Comment: Yes did. Thank you grace!